# How to add a graphics frame to an image without resampling

Tags: graphics, image

Using `Inset` to place an image inside a `Graphics` expression with `Frame -> True` provides a simple way to add a scale bar, or ruler, to the image. However, I cannot find a way to get the resulting graphics to display with a one-to-one correspondence between image pixels and screen pixels. For certain images this creates nasty artifacts.

Here's an example of an image which shouldn't be resampled:

```
i = Image[Array[Boole[OddQ[#1 + #2]] &, {200, 200}]]
```

[image]

Suppose this image represents a region of space 0.2 m wide. To show a "ruler" I can insert the image into a graphics frame like this:

```
With[{x = 0.2}, 
 Graphics[Inset[i, {0, 0}, Center, x], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> x/2]]
```

[image]

The problem is quite clear - that checkerboard effect is not present in the original image. By adding an `ImageSize` option or manually resizing the graphics I can change the unwanted pattern, but I can't get rid of it completely.

My question is whether there is a way to embed an image into graphics so that the image is displayed at its "natural" size, i.e. with one image pixel per screen pixel. Alternatively, is there a better way to display a scale bar or ruler alongside the image?

Comment: `Texture` seems to be using some other resampling algorithm (that also is destructive) `{Texture[i], Polygon[{{-x/2, -x/2}, {x/2, -x/2}, {x/2, x/2}, {-x/2, x/2}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I figured it out and now it seems blindingly obvious!

[@ssch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1517/ssch) had the right idea - set the image size to `ImageDimensions[i]` plus a little bit extra. The question is how to choose exactly the right little bit extra...

If the image perfectly fills the plot range, then the extra is the part of the graphic outside the plot range, this is of course determined by the `ImagePadding` option. So the solution is simply to use both `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` and make sure that the difference between the two is exactly the size of the embedded image.

For example with a 200 pixel image and 50 pixels of padding (40 on the left and bottom, 10 on the right and top):

```
i = Image[Array[Boole[OddQ[#1 + #2]] &, {200, 200}]];
With[{x = 0.2}, 
 Graphics[Inset[i, {0, 0}, Center, x], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> x/2, 
  ImageSize -> 200 + 50, ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {40, 10}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Applying `Rasterize` to the image almost works right away:

```
With[{x = 0.2}, 
 Graphics[Inset[Rasterize@i, {0, 0}, Center, x], Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> x/2]]
```

[image: initial]

Manual re-sizing of the `Graphics` yield:

[image: manual]

The same thing can be achieved without `Rasterize` by giving explicit `ImageSize` when creating the `Image`:

```
i = Image[Array[Boole[OddQ[#1 + #2]] &, {200, 200}], ImageSize -> {200, 200}]
With[{x = 0.2}, 
 Graphics[Inset[i, {0, 0}, Center, x], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> x/2]
]
```

The manual resizing should be possible to avoid if there is a way to specifically set the `Graphics` content size to be equal that of the image.

Giving `Graphics` `ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[i] + {45, 45}` seems pretty good for this case.

Comment: This is useful, I didn't realise the `ImageSize` option had that effect. Unfortunately, as your first image shows, it's possible to manually resize the frame without changing the image, so a careless user might get the scale wrong. Ideally I'd like the image to be initially displayed at its natural size but allow it to scale up or down if the graphic is manually resized.

Comment: @SimonWoods I think allowing any resizing at all will be very difficult, image rescaling is often destructive in one way or another. Here's a toy you can try some built-in resampling algorithms with. I found none to be satisfactory for this image: `Manipulate[
 ImageResize[i, w, Resampling -> resampling]
 , {w, 10, 500}
 , {resampling, {"Nearest", "Bilinear", "Biquadratic", "Bicubic", 
   "Gaussian", "Lanczos", "Cosine", "Hamming", "Hann", "Blackman", 
   "Bartlett", "Connes", "Welch", "Parzen", "Kaiser"}}]`

Comment: Oh, any resizing of this image will surely ruin it. The aim is to display it *initially* at the right size - if someone later decides to manually resize it they will have to put up with the poor quality.