# Use custom frame ticks on an image

Tags: image, ticks

I chose as an example a familiar figure!

```
img = Import["Lena.jpg"];
```

Now let's confine her inside a frame

```
S0 = Show[img, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Mathematica decides (I don't know how) to range the frame from 0 to about 300.

Is there a way to change the default range of the frame?

(a). A square frame like `PlotRange -> {{-n,n},{-n,n}}`

(b). A random frame with `PlotRange -> {{a,b},{c,d}}`

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30095/862)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Graphics[ {
   Texture @ img, 
   Polygon[Scaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> ({{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}})]
   },
   Axes        -> False, 
   Frame       -> True,
   PlotRange   -> {{-10, 15}, {-102, 4}},
   AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio @ img,
   BaseStyle   -> 18
]
```

[image]

Comment: `Inset[]` is another possibility.

Comment: Nice but there is a blue dot above Lena's hat at (1,1)! Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: @J.M. good luck with placement/size ;) I don't know how to handle that, but if I missed something, I will gladly upvote such answer.

Comment: Now when I evaluate your code I get the following error `ListPlot::argx: ListPlot called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`

Comment: v9.0 complains about the empty list! I have v10.2 in another PC and I will check it later on!

Comment: One solution would be to set that rebel point at an extreme position let's say at {9999,9999}, so as to be absent from the plot. What do you think?

Comment: Yes! Now everything is as it should be. Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `Graphics` instead of `ListPlot`?

Comment: @SimonWoods Good point :p it's an artifact after initial approach with `DataRange` :)

Answer (score 4):

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
Show[i, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
        FrameTicks -> {{{0, "Here"}, {200, "Mine"}, {400, "Yours"}},
                       {{0, "Here"}, {300, "Lena"}, {500, "Beauty"}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

r = Transpose[{#, #/5}] &[Range[0, 500, 100]];

Show[img, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  FrameTicks -> {{r, None}, {r, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. This comment also applies to @belisarius answer. You use custom `FrameTicks`  and therefore you lose all the sub ticks...